# Prove summation of squares of partial derivatives is equal to the derivative of a function squared

Tags: real-analysis, partial-derivative, normed-spaces, chain-rule

> **Problem** Let $u = f(r)$ and $r = |\mathbf{x}| =(x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2)^{1/2}$. Show that $\sum_{1}^{n} (\dfrac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x_j}}) ^ {2} = [f'(r)]^2$

I expanded the LHS to be
$$
\sum_{1}^{n} (\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j})^2 = (\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{r_1}} \frac{\partial{r_1}}{\partial{x_1}} + \dots + \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{r_n}} \frac{\partial{r_n}}{\partial{x_1}})^2 + (\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{r_1}} \frac{\partial{r_1}}{\partial{x_2}} + \dots + \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{r_n}} \frac{\partial{r_n}}{\partial{x_2}})^2 + \dots (\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{r_1}} \frac{\partial{r_1}}{\partial{x_n}} + \dots + \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{r_n}} \frac{\partial{r_n}}{\partial{x_n}})^2
$$

Is this correct? I have no idea how to evaluate the RHS. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It's not correct. You only have a single $r$, not multiple $r_{j}$. We have $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{j}} = \frac{df}{dr} \cdot \frac{\partial r}{\partial x_{j}} = f'(r) \frac{x_{j}}{r} \implies \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{j}} \right)^{2} = (f'(r))^{2} \cdot \frac{x_{j}^{2}}{r^{2}}$$ Now sum over $j$.